# Edittext place cursor at the end of a Hint

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is it possible to place somehow cursor at the end of a **hint** (not end of a **text**)?
Method `setSelection()` is not working (throws `IndexOutOfBounds` exception, as length of text is 0).

Comment: No. A hint is **not editable**. You can't set a cursor there. It just wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Why would you want that? Do you want to continue editing from the hint?

Comment: No, I want it to look more estethic. Now cursor is placed at the beginning of a hint and I don't like how it looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a trick.First you get hint string and hint color then you set EditText's text (value equals hint string) and do not forget set textcolor (values hint color).When user clicks the EditText, you can change the color back while reset empty text.

```
    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_id);
    String hint = editText.getHint().toString();
    ColorStateList hintTextColor = editText.getHintTextColors();
    final ColorStateList textColor = editText.getTextColors();
    editText.setTextColor(hintTextColor);
    editText.setText(hint);
    editText.setSelection(hint.length());

    editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setTextColor(textColor);
            editText.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it. That might be a closest approach to what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put the cursor based on the hint.  However, what you can do is append the text you want to the EditText and then the cursor will be after that.  You can then add a TextWatcher to prevent the user from deleting the appended (hint) text.  Here's some code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String HINT = "Name: ";
private EditText editText;

private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher()
{
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        if (!s.toString().startsWith(HINT))
        {
            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            editText.setText("");
            editText.append(HINT);
            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {

    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    editText.append(HINT);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you put your hint as regular EditText content as hint is not one.  But that defeats the purpose of the hint feature...